# Tkinter Listbox.get(ANCHOR) not grabbing correct item when arrow keys are used to scroll

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, anchor

Consider the below piece of Python code

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Listbox Test")
root.geometry("200x300")

def ShowSelected():
    ShowText.config(text = Box.get(ANCHOR))

Box = Listbox(root)
Box.pack()
Box.insert(0, "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet")

ShowButton = Button(root, text="Show Selected", command = ShowSelected)
ShowButton.pack(pady=20)
ShowText = Label(root)
ShowText.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

- If I click the listbox item *Indigo*, then press the *Show Selected* button, text appears at the bottom that says *Indigo*. This is as intended
- If I then click the item *Yellow* & press the button, the text updates from *Indigo* to *Yellow*
- If I then click *Red*, then press the down arrow key (moving the blue highlight bar from *Red* to *Orange*), then press the button, the text updates to *Red* instead of *Orange*, as *Red* was the previously clicked item. It should instead update to *Orange*, as *Orange* is the currently selected item

After some searching, I've been unable to find a way to set the ANCHOR of a listbox without actually clicking it. If such a function exists (or doesn't exist, meaning that a workaround is needed), all help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Use `ACTIVE` instead of `ANCHOR`.

Comment: Thanks! Man, I don't know how I missed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Box.get(ACTIVE)` instead of `Box.get(ANCHOR)` solves this issue. Credit to acw1668 for this

Also, as an extension of this, consider a version where instead of using the ShowButton widget to update the text, you use `Box.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", ShowSelected)`. Assuming you can only select one Listbox item at a time, `Box.get(Box.curselection())` is the best solution, as `Box.get(ACTIVE)` will cause left-click selections to show the previously selected option instead of the currently selected option